# Converting Audio Blob to text in Python using Speech recognition

Tags: python, html, speech-recognition

Apologies for the English....

I am building a chatbot application where voice is recorded on client side  through HTML5's mediaRecorder api and sent as Formdata to python's falcon web service.

On Python side i need to directly convert this audio blob to text.

Currently I am writing this audio blob to a wav file and then reading from that file. However it is taking a long time in this process as FileIO is involved. I need to somehow directly consume this audio blob as input source for speech recognition.

This is What I have tried:

```
def on_post(self, req, resp):         

    open("backend.wav",'wb')
      .write(req.get_param('audio_data').file.read());

    mic = sr.AudioFile('backend.wav')
    with mic as source:
       print("Speak !!")
       audio = r.record(source)

    #audio = req
    results = r.recognize_google(audio_data=audio, language="en-US",show_all=True)

    return results;
```

I am not an experienced Python Developer ,So please pardon if it's a stupid question. Any help is highly appreciated..

Comment: if I not wrong `speek_recognition` works only with filename and it has no option to get directly from memory. It can't even use file-like object so it can't use `io.BytesIO` which creates file-like object in memory. But maybe I'm wrong and it was different module.

Comment: Dear Furas, Seems like there is an sr.AudioData() function which takes input as : 'frame_data', 'sample_rate', and 'sample_width'. However When I tried that,I got     
with "mic as source:
AttributeError: __enter__"

Comment: you could put this in question with full error message (Traceback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it but it could work.

It seems that `AudioFile` can use file-object so this code uses `io.BytesIO` to create file-object in memory and save data in this file. This way it doesn't have to use disk.

```
import io


def on_post(self, req, resp):    

    f = req.get_param('audio_data').file

    file_obj = io.BytesIO()  # create file-object
    file_obj.write(f.read()) # write in file-object
    file_obj.seek(0) # move to beginning so it will read from beginning

    mic = sr.AudioFile(file_obj) # use file-object
    with mic as source:
         audio = r.record(source)

    result = r.recognize_google(audio_data=audio, language="en-US", show_all=True)

    return result
```

Comment: Thanks furas for your fast response,Really appreciate it.
I tried your solution, but it's giving error :
"Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format"

Comment: I could test it only on file from disk - `f = open(filename, 'rb')` - and it seems it works.

Comment: Yeah it works with filename. I will keep looking for a way how it can be done with audio blob.

Comment: it is very wierd that it doesn't work. `BytesIO` creates file the same way as normal file. And I didn't have problem with `AudioFile(file_obj)`. As for me only explanation can be broken data from `req.get_param('audio_data').file`